# Creating a Hibernate inner join when there is no explicit mapping between two GORM objects

Tags: hibernate, groovy, grails-orm

I have a GORM object that looks like this:

```
class GromObjectClassName {

  String userId

  // CRUD ATTRS
  String id
  Date dateCreated
  Date lastUpdated
  Long version
}
```

the userId string belongs to the User GORM object

```
class User {
   String id
```

However, as you can tell, there is no direct reference to the User GORM object in my GormObject but rather an implicit understanding that this userID belongs to the ID of User.

I can't unfortunately change this, but I am trying to write a query that in SQL would look like this:

```
Select * From TABLE t inner join User u on t.userId = u.id
```

But I can't do this since Hibernate requires me to explicitly specify the mapping between objects for me to perform an innerjoin using the createAlias feature.

I do not want to write an HQL query, so what is the way forward?

Comment: Solution: USE HQL or SQL. Criteria API does **not** support this.

Comment: If your version of GORM supports the new [advanced subqueries](http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/introduction.html#whatsNew24) for where queries, you could perhaps help yourself with the `exists`  clause with subqueries..